# Maui publish error "The RuntimeIdentifier 'android-arm' is invalid."

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, maui

I create new maui blazor project and try to publish it for android, but at the and of publish
a have error

```
The RuntimeIdentifier 'android-arm' is invalid.
```

I set targer "android-arm", and i have a same issues with other targets.

Try on VS2022 17.1.0 preview 5

ps i installed workloads but it did not help.

ps2 try it on Win10 18362

Answer (score 0):

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

Reinstall sdk or update to latest version bug fixes